# Как правильно убрать часть изменений из коммита из ветки, которую уже отправил на сервер?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-commit

Клонировал feature-branch из репозитория на gitlab. Вносил изменения, делал несколько комитов, отправлял обратно ветку на сервер.
Теперь требуется убрать часть изменений из нескольких коммитов (кое-где pycharm автоматически понадобавлял пустые строки, пробелы). Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это правильнее всего сделать?

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, вопрос. Вас интересует техническая сторона вопроса или логика действий?

Comment: Интересует и логика, и техническая сторона. Я попробую сделать как вы написали ниже, спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть два основных способа:

1. Добавляем в ветку еще один коммит, который приводит файлы к нужному состоянию. В комментарии можно написать что-то вроде "подготовка к слиянию"
2. При помощи интерактивного `rebase` отредактировать каждый из своих коммитов, после чего сделать `push --force`

Первый способ более безопасен и осуществим всегда. Но в истории останутся ненужные правки. Он недопустим если, например, в коммит попали реальные пароли внутри конфигурационного файла.

Делать `push --force` в уже опубликованную ветку считается крайне некрасивым, а иногда это еще и опасно. Придется оповестить всех, кто также может работать с этой веткой. GitLab, например, автоматически запрещать force-push в master. Чтоб это провернуть придется попросить разрешения у администратора. Но по моему мнению для feature-branch это не только допустимо, но и является предпочтительным способом.

Comment: Воспользовался методом 2, то что нужно, спасибо.